# Displaying query in browser with table

Tags: php, sqlite

Hi there i am using a sqlite database and i have written a query in php that is running. However i cant seem to build a solution that will display the results of this query in the browser (tabular or other). Here is my code. This is the last element of this system so help is appreciated.

Code:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:daypilot.sqlite'); 
$start = '2018-02-20'; 
$end = '2018-02-25'; 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE end > ? AND start < ?'; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); $stmt->execute([$start, $end]); 
$events = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

---

[Update] From comment, OP has tried

```
<table> 
   <tr> 
      <th>id</th> <th>name</th> <th>contact</th> 
   </tr> 

<?php foreach ($events as $event): ?> 

   <tr> 
       <td><?php echo $event['id'] ?></td> 
       <td><?php echo $event['name'] ?></td>   
       <td><?php echo $event['contact'] ?></td> 
    </tr> 

<?php endforeach; ?> 

</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Do you have any code to show us? Maybe a for loop over `$events` which builds `<table>` row by row? Show us some code and we will help you, but please don't expect us to code it for you; that wouldn't help you at all

Comment: <table>
<tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>contact</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($events as $event): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $event['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['contact'] ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

Comment: I have used code like that multipe times and has not worked for me

Comment: I added your code into the question and formatted it; otherwise, it is unlikely that anyone will read this. You should always post all code when asking.

Comment: very sorry im new to stackoverflow apolgies. This table code doesnt work when i combine it with the query code. Any reasons why ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:daypilot.sqlite'); 
$start = '2018-02-20'; 
$end = '2018-02-25'; 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE end > ? AND start < ?'; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); $stmt->execute([$start, $end]); 
$events = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$table = '<table>';

foreach($events as $event) {
    $table .= '   <tr>';
    $table .= '      <td>' . $event['column_name'] . '</td>';
    // repeat for every column you want to add
    $table .= '   </tr>';
}

$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
?>
```

Well, this is the simplest (and not the best) way to build the HTML table. You should insert that snippet code in the place where you want the table appears.

I passed `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to fetchAll method to ensure that the data are returned as associative array, then you have to iterate over it and extract the desired columns

Comment: Thank you so much this works. Being trying this for days. Appreciate it

Comment: @RyanHill please tick the question as answered.

Comment: That's how I would have done it too. All of that dropping in & out of PHP makes it difficult to read.

Comment: RyanHill as @MikeT suggests, please mark the question as answered so people won't add more comments/answers and they will know which solution worked for you

Comment: @RyanHill please follow up on answers given that help you out, by clicking the 'accept' checkmark next to them. By showing proper thanks to those who took the time to help you, it encourages people to continue to helping on stackoverflow in general. Its a community effort :)