# User input dates for query in sqlite database

Tags: php, sqlite

Hi there i have successfully coded a query that displays the records between two specific dates from my sqlite database. However i am unsure how to run a query whereby a user inputs two dates into fields and the records between these two dates will be displayed. This is the code that i have written so far. The first batch of code is the query that runs perfectly in the browser. The second two batches of code are practice templates for the user put type query i need but i am quite unsure on how to do it. I wanted to provide some code to ensure that i at least tried something. Help is much appreciated

```
    <?php
// knew most part how yo connect to database and query. Got help with table display here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025289/displaying-query-in-browser-with-table/49025603#49025603"
$db = new PDO('sqlite:daypilot.sqlite'); 
$start = '2018-02-20'; 
$end = '2018-02-25'; 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE end > ? AND start < ?'; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); $stmt->execute([$start, $end]); 
$events = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$table = '<table>';
foreach($events as $event) {
    $table .= '<tr>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $event['id'] . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $event['name'] . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $event['start'] . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $event['end'] . '</td>';

    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
?>
```

```
<body>

<form action='http://localhost/home.php'>
    Title: <input type=text name=title /><br />
    Body: <input type=text name=body /> 
    <input type=submit />
</form>

</body>

</html>


<html>

<head></head>

<body>
<?php
$post = array(
    'title' => $GET['title'], 
    'body' => $GET['body']
);
echo "<h1>".$post['title']."</h1>";
echo "<p>".$post['body']."</p>";
echo "<hr />";
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is just the query logic.

Your WHERE clause

```
WHERE end > ? AND start < ?'
```

would generate

```
WHERE end > '2018-02-20' AND start < '2018-02-25'
```

Instead do this

```
$start = '2018-02-20'; 
$end = '2018-02-25'; 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE start > ? AND end < ?'; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute([$start, $end]);
```

Which should generate

```
WHERE start > '2018-02-20' AND end < '2018-02-25'
```

And with a form wrapped around it

```
<body>

<?php
    // make sure the form has actually been submitted
    // and its not just been loaded from a click on a link etc
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if ( isset($_POST['start'], $_POST['end']) ) {

            $db = new PDO('sqlite:daypilot.sqlite');

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE start > ? AND end < ?"; 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
            $stmt->execute([$_POST['start'], $_POST['end']]); 
            $events = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            $table = '<table>';
            foreach ($events as $event) {
                $table .= '<tr>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['id'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['name'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['start'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['end'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '</tr>';
            }
            $table .= '</table>';
            echo $table;
        }
    }
?>
    <form action='http://localhost/home.php' method="POST">
        Title: <input type="text" name="start" /><br />
        Body: <input type="text" name="end" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

> Note: if you enter that dates in any other format than `'2018-02-20'` you may have to add some checks and convert any other formats to the correct format

Comment: Thanks for advice I didnt spot this !!. Can you recommend simple code whereby user inputs two dates into two text fields and the query would display the records between these two dates.

Comment: Any help on how i can make a form where a user must input dates into two text fields and the query will return the records beteen these two dates

Comment: There you go, have a look at that